# capifony's installing Composer dependencies failed

Tags: symfony, capifony

i try to deploy my symfony2 project with the help of capifony

```
cap  deploy:setup
```

makes no problem and store on /var/www/htdocs/symfony-project two folders

```
.symfony-project 
 .. releases
 .. shared
```

after that, when i try to run:

```
cap  deploy:cold
```

i get

```
--> Updating code base with remote_cache strategy
--> Creating cache directory................................✔
--> Creating symlinks for shared directories................✔
--> Normalizing asset timestamps............................✔
--> Downloading Composer....................................✔
--> Installing Composer dependencies........................✘
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
failed: "sh -c 'sh -c '\\''cd /var/www/htdocs/symfony-project/releases/20130311124645 &&      
php composer.phar install --no-scripts --verbose --prefer-dist --optimize-
autoloader'\\'''" on webservername.net
```

and there are no folders in

```
var/www/htdocs/symfony-project/releases/
```

my deploy.rb is the following one:

```
set :user, "user"
set :port, "12345"

set :application, "Application Name"
set :domain,      "webservername.net"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/htdocs/symfony-project"
set :app_path,    "app"


set :repository,  "ssh://#{user}@webservername.net:#{port}/var/repos/symfony-project.git"
set :scm,         :git
set :branch,      "master"

set :model_manager, "doctrine"

role :web,        domain                        
role :app,        domain                         
role :db,         domain, :primary => true       

set  :use_sudo,      false
set  :keep_releases,  3

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :use_composer, true
```

has anyone an Idea what could it be caused by?

Comment: When i'm experiencing problems with capifony deploy i use the -d option. Step-wise to verify which command is breaking the deployment.. when i located the exact command, i'm executing the very same command on the server itself, which will show more information (missing privileges etc.. )

Comment: Definitely worth doing as @weyandch suggests. You wont have a release if it's rolled back so that is right. Also, increase LOGGER level to get more verbose error messages; logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you face a permission problem. Make sure you are entirely owner of your local *.composer/* directory.

**sudo chown -R user:user ~/.composer/** should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I faced the same error message. But the reason was a **dependency which could not be resolved by composer**.

Running `cap staging deploy -d` and stepping through each command, as @weyandch suggested, helped to find the command which failed.